# Inconsistency with generated SQL query when using MathExpressions.round

Tags: sql, querydsl

I am trying to create a query where I need to add rounding to one selected field (setting decimal place 1).

This is my code:

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);              
QMyEntity myEntity = QMyEntity.myEntity;        
QSecondaryEntity secondaryEntity = QSecondaryEntity.secondaryEntity;    

Expression<String> idExpression= (new CaseBuilder()
            .when(myEntity.type.eq(4)).then(myEntity.normalId)
            .otherwise(myEntity.specialId)).as("id");

NumberExpression<BigDecimal> roundExpression = MathExpressions.round(myEntity.qty, 1).as("roundedQty");

query = query.from(browse, lips).where(predicate);

return query.list(Projections.constructor(MyEntityDto.class, myEntity.field1, myEntity.field2, roundExpression, idExpression));
```

MyEntity is not directly mapping a database table called "MyEntity", but "Table0".

When I see the generated query I see:

```
select myEntity.field1, myEntity.field2, round(myEntity.qty),
       (case when (myEntity.type = ?1) then myEntity.normalId
                                       else myEntity.specialId end) as id
from MyEntity myEntity
where myEntity.id = ?2 and ...
```

And I get this error:

> The SELECT clause has 'round' and '(myEntity.qty)' that are not
>   separated by a comma.

Whereas if I remove the round expression the generated query is ok and querying the correct table in the database:

```
SELECT t1.Field1 AS a1, t0.Field2 AS a2, t0.Quantity AS a3,
       CASE  WHEN (t0.Type = ?) THEN t3.ID ELSE t3.SecondID END 
FROM Table7 t7, Table t6,..., Table1 t1, Table0 t0 
WHERE ((((((((t ...
```

Am I using the MathExpression correctly? What is the correct way of rounding a field in the select clause?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a library bug. If you try to do the same query otherwise to put 'round' with quotes it will fail also:

```
Expression round = TemplateExpressionImpl.create(BigDecimal.class, "'round(myEntity.qty, 1)' as roundedQty");
```

or

```
Expression round2 = TemplateExpressionImpl.create(BigDecimal.class, "'round({0}, {1})' as roundedQty", myEntity.qty, 1);
```

You could try using createQuery, but you have to indicate the complete query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT round(myEntity.qty, 1) FROM MyEntity myEntity WHERE ....");
```

It fails also, however with createQuery you can put the quotes and it will work:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT 'round(myEntity.qty, 1)' FROM MyEntity myEntity WHERE ....");
```